# bootstrap 5.2 tooltip not accepting the right function signature for placement: parameter

Tags: javascript, webpack, bootstrap-5

I am using webpack to compile the following javascript / bootstrap 5.2.3 code.

```js
$('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
   placement: function(tt, trigger) {   
      return 'top'; 
   },
});
```

But I am getting the compiler error:

```
TS2322: Type '(tt: any, trigger: any) => string' is not assignable to
type  'PopoverPlacement | (() => PopoverPlacement)'.
```

My code works if I remove the `(tt, trigger)` parameters. However I need the trigger parameter in order to identify the element which triggered the tooltip. According to the bootstrap 5.2 documentation it should take 2 params:

> When a function is used to determine the placement, it is called with
> the  popover DOM node as its first argument and the triggering element
> DOM node as its second. The this context is set to the popover
> instance.

Why is it not working with the correct parameters?

Comment: I see now that I'm using the @types/bootstrap package from DefinitelyTyped to define typescript types and it looks like the package is wrong/incomplete.

Comment: bootstrap 5 is jQuery-less